# How to export data of a table as insert query in Teradata SQL assistance

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata.
I have a table that consists of around 600 records.
I want to get the insert query of these records. In oracle SQL developer i used to export it and there was an option as "insert query". How do i achieve this in Teradata SQL assistance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to get INSERTs for all the rows in a result set using SQL Assistant.

There's an ugly workaround using the `CSV`-UDF like:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (  -- put your select here
   SELECT * FROM dbc.tablesV
 )
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
 (CSV(NEW VARIANT_TYPE( -- you need to list each column of your table
       cte.DataBaseName                  
      ,cte.TABLENAME                     
      ,cte.Version                       
      ,cte.TableKind                     
      ,cte.ProtectionType                
      ,cte.JournalFlag                   
      ,cte.CreatorName                   
      ,cte.RequestText                   
      ,cte.CommentString                 
      ,cte.ParentCount                   
      ,cte.ChildCount                    
      ,cte.NamedTblCheckCount            
      ,cte.UnnamedTblCheckExist          
      ,cte.PrimaryKeyIndexId             
      ,cte.RepStatus                     
      ,cte.CreateTimeStamp               
      ,cte.LastAlterName                 
      ,cte.LastAlterTimeStamp            
      ,cte.RequestTxtOverflow            
      ,cte.AccessCount                   
      ,cte.LastAccessTimeStamp           
      ,cte.UtilVersion                   
      ,cte.QueueFlag                     
      ,cte.CommitOpt                     
      ,cte.TransLog                      
      ,cte.CheckOpt                      
      ,cte.TemporalProperty              
      ,cte.ResolvedCurrent_Date          
      ,cte.ResolvedCurrent_Timestamp     
      ,cte.SystemDefinedJI               
      ,cte.VTQualifier                   
      ,cte.TTQualifier                   
      ,cte.PIColumnCount                 
      ,cte.PartitioningLevels            
      ,cte.LoadProperty                  
      ,cte.CurrentLoadId                 
      ,cte.LoadIdLayout                  
      ,cte.DelayedJI                     
     ), ',', '"')
   RETURNS (op VARCHAR(32000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
 ) AS dt;
```

Otherwise you must use a different tool...

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 600 records, wouldn't it be easier just to export from SQL*Assistant into Excel or Access and manipulate them using Office tools.

Another alternative - connect Teradata as a linked server in SQL Server Management Studio and use the function "script as insert" from inside of it.